# Paypal API create sandbox Personal and Business account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I try to find in the huge, huge, Paypal documentation the way to create a couple Personal account, and business account, to test the API.

So I follow the first step on the guide https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/ but in the subscribe page https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/account-selection it seems I am about to create a real account, instead of a sandbox account ?..

So what is the correct way and URLs to create a **Personal account**, and a **Business account** in the **sandbox** environment, and how/where to get the ClientID and ClientSecret ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to http://developer.paypal.com and login with your live PayPal account.
2. Click the Dashboard link at the top, right.
3. On the left side menu, under Sandbox, click Accounts.
4. At the top, right click Create Account.
5. Follow the steps to create a business or personal account.
6. Repeat the steps as necessary to create additional accounts as necessary.

The sandbox accounts will allow you to generate API credentials like username, password, signature.  For ClientID and ClientSecret you'll need to create an app.  This differs depending on which API you're using, but happens from the same place.

1. Go to http://developer.paypal.com and login with your live PayPal account.
2. Click Dashboard.
3. On the left, click My Apps & Credentials.
4. If you're using Braintree v.zero you'll click the "Generate Credential" button under that section.

If you're using the REST API you'd click "Create App" under that section.

If you're using the Adaptive Payments API you'd scroll down to NVP/SOAP and click the link for "Create and Manage NVP/SOAP Apps."  That will move you away to another page where you may have to login again with your live PayPal account, and then you'll be able to create your app.

After the app is created, you'll be able to click into the app details to see the ID/Secret values.